# Limit methods of a class to only those of a interface

Tags: java, oop

Lets say I have:

```
public interface IFoo{
    public void bar();
}
```

and

```
public class Foo implements IFoo{
    public void bar(){
        //bar...
    }
}
```

But IFoo is new and Foo is the only thing that implements it for now.

I want to make sure someone else doesn't accidentally add additional methods to Foo without adding them to IFoo as well.

Is there anyway to ensure this in java?

Comment: You could write a Test using reflections which will fail if any Class implementing IFoo has a (public) method which isn't part of IFoo.

Comment: This is unnecessarily restrictive.

Comment: If you only code against the interface in the rest of your codebase, anything added to `Foo` and not `IFoo` won't be visible.  It won't keep people from adding things only to `Foo`, but they'll notice really quickly when they try to use them...

Comment: Why would it be a problem? If you "[program to the interface](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/232359/202153)", then you're ensured that any method that should be called must be in the interface. It is still valid to add extra methods to the implementing class, but those methods cannot be used unless they are also added to the interface. Preventing the addition of extra methods without knowing why someone would want that is too restrictive, as @SotiriosDelimanolis said. Let them. They cannot be used from the interface, but maybe that's the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At program startup, read the class definition using reflection and from there you can get the Methods defined in the class.  If you find another method, throw an exception.

```
Class aClass = ...//obtain class object
Method[] methods = aClass.getMethods();
```

Another way would be to use compile time annotations: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/java-annotation-processors.html
But someone could remove your custom annotation from the class code.